# Removing redundant folder paths from a list

Tags: java, c#

I have the following list which contains a series of folder paths. Some of these are redundant so I need to remove them and the final list should only contain the bottom level folders:

Initial list:

```
var paths = new List<string>
{
    "Pavements/",
    "Pavements/2019_05/",
    "Pavements/2019_06/",
    "Pavements/2019_06/A/",
    "Roads/",
    "Roads/2019_06/"
};
```

The final List should look like:

```
paths =
{
    "Pavements/2019_05/",
    "Pavements/2019_06/A/",
    "Roads/2019_06/"
};
```

i.e. all the upper level folder paths have been removed.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I have a feeling I need a recursive method but am unsure how to go about it. I am using C# but answer in java or something similar is ok.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with a linq query that compares each item to all the other items and returns the item only if none of the others begin with it:

```
paths = paths.Where(path => !paths.Any(p => p != path && p.StartsWith(path))).ToList();
```